# jquery ui sortable: connected with and not connected with?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

`sortable`'s `connectWith` seems strange. For instance, I have a list of sortable items (orange) that I **don't** want them to connect with other sortable connected list items (yellow).

So I add a class name to those are connected `connected-sortable`, but the ones (orange) are not connected still can be dropped into the connected list.

Why is that? How can I fix this - the orange items **should not be dropped** into among the yellow items.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2RJj/).

jquery,

```
 $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
                connectWith: ".connected-sortable",
                cancel: ".not-sortable",
                handle: '.handle',
                update: function(){

                   // php updates  

                }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call sortable twice where .sortable is yellow and .sortable2 is orange (don't forget to add .sortable2 li to your css).

```
$(function() {
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connected-sortable",
            cancel: ".not-sortable",
            handle: '.handle',
            update: function(){

                var path = $(this).closest(".parent-sortable").find('input.path-sort-image').val();
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
                //alert(path);
                //alert(order);


            }
        });
$( ".sortable2" ).sortable({             
            cancel: ".not-sortable",
            handle: '.handle',
            update: function(){

                var path = $(this).closest(".parent-sortable").find('input.path-sort-image').val();
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
                //alert(path);
                //alert(order);


            }
        });
    });
```

I also updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2RJj/1/).
I hope this helps.